# Where in AWS to store large chunks of HTML content associated with database records

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I have a web application that uses MySQL database records to render pages.

Each record has the following:

- ID (primary key)
- Additional fields of various types (integer, varchar, long, etc.)
- A field of type text (or mediumtext) to store chunks of static HTML that is displayed on the page

The static HTML is never used in joins and is not meant to be searchable. It is only retrieved when the entire record is retrieved by primary key.

So far, things worked smoothly. However, as the table size increases, I am thinking that it may be more efficient to store the static HTML text external to MySQL.

The MySQL database runs in AWS RDS. So, I was thinking of using another AWS service to store the text data. So my current options are:

- Keep everything in MySQL without worrying about table size (it currently approaching 1 gigabyte and growing quickly).
- Use S3 objects for the HTML text data and reference them by either the primary key or something like UUID that is stored in the table
- Use DynamoDB for the HTML text data and reference the values with keys stored in the database (or by the same primary key)

My concern with option 1 is table size. The concern with options two and three is syncing issues and having to make an additional call on the server side to get the data when rendering the page. My understanding is that DynamoDB would be faster than S3 for data retrieval, but it has a size limit per record and could get expensive and messy dealing with capacity units and such.

Any guidance would help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any latency requirements for retrieving the html?

Comment: @MatthewPope - the faster the better as the data should be retrieved on the server side before the page is rendered. I would say should be in the milliseconds.

Comment: Are these html resources infrequently used resource, or will they be used many times by many users? Do they *need* to be loaded server side, or could you have them loaded by the client directly?

Comment: @MatthewPope - they are used frequently. They need to be loaded on the server side. The site is public-facing and SEO is a big concern, so AJAX content loading is out

Comment: @MatthewPope - clarification: some records are used very frequently and others rarely used. I am not currently implementing any server-side caching if that's what you're thinking

Comment: What do you think is the upper limit on the size of an individual html resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have accurately identified the trade offs between DynamoDB and S3.

I think the simplest solution is to use S3. Keeping things in sync between S3 and MySQL is not as difficult or error prone as you might think. One of the applications I work on professionally uses that strategy (for a different use case) and we have never had any operational burden related to S3 data being out of sync from our main database.

Yes, the latency from S3 is higher than DynamoDB. You can expect <10 ms from DynamoDB vs tens to a few hundreds of milliseconds from S3 (assuming the object is <= 400 kB, the DynamoDB item size limit). However, S3 does not require you to provision capacity, and practically speaking, there is no limit on file sizes. (Technically, a single file can’t be more than 5TB, but you’re unlikely to reach that for this use case.)

Unless you know you need *single-digit millisecond latency*, you should use S3. It is designed for this very thing.

S3 guarantees strong consistency when an object is created, but only eventual consistency when it is updated. If this is a concern for you, make sure you just create a new object each time you would normally update it. Since you are storing a key in your database, you’re not tied to a specific file name and it’s easy to generate a new key every time you modify the html.

If you build it with S3, and the latency ends up being too high, you can put a cache in front of S3 or you could try moving to a Serverless model using Lambda@Edge with CloudFront for serving the static resources from S3.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. I think anything over 50 ms would be more latency than what should be allocated for this particular part of the application. What disadvantage other than planning ahead for capacity and the max 4k size do you see with DynamoDB, if any?

Comment: With DynamoDB, you pay for what you provision. With S3, you pay for what you use.

Comment: Right. I don't think cost would be an issue in this particular application. My main concern was the fact that you can't easily verify the syncing between RDS and DynamoDB because scanning all records from DynamoDB is a pain and you have to manually up the capacity before scanning and then lower it once done. But I guess that's something I will have to get used to.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that S3's bandwidth is almost unlimited. The bottleneck for retrieving data from S3 is your own server's network connection. If you choose a large enough EC2 instance type, you might not have to worry about latency from S3.

Comment: You shouldn't have to use a table scan to keep things in sync. You might be able to come up with a system using DynamoDB streams to solve that problem.

Comment: Ah. Interesting. Thanks. I didn't know that. I use multiple EC2 instances behind a fire wall. so they are small and the bandwidth would likely be low too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184289/discussion-between-matthew-pope-and-stepanian).

Comment: Cool. I will look into DynamoDB streams. What I mean by "syncing" is periodically check to see if all records in MySQL are accounted for in DynamoDB. I may not even need to do that.